# How to specify cryptdevice by label using systemd boot?

Tags: kernel, luks, dm-crypt, systemd-boot

I'm running Arch Linux with systemd boot. In `/boot/loader/entries/arch.conf` I currently specify the luks crypto device with a line like this:

```
options        rw cryptdevice=/dev/sda1:ABC root=/dev/mapper/ABC
```

I know I can also use UUID instead of `/dev/sda1`. In that case the kernel options line would look like this:

```
options        rw cryptdevice=UUID=1f5cce52-8299-9221-b2fc-19cebc959f51:ABC root=/dev/mapper/ABC
```

However, can I instead use either a partition **label** or a volume **label** or any other kind of label? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're already using the new LUKS2 format, you can set a label:

For new LUKS2 containers:

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat --type=luks2 --label=foobar foobar.img
# blkid /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: UUID="fda16145-822e-405c-9fe8-fe7e7f0ddb5e" LABEL="foobar" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

For existing LUKS2 containers:

```
# cryptsetup config --label=barfoo /dev/loop0
# blkid /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: UUID="fda16145-822e-405c-9fe8-fe7e7f0ddb5e" LABEL="barfoo" TYPE="crypto_LUKS"
```

However, it's not possible to set a label for the more common LUKS1 header.

---

With LUKS1, you can only set a label on a higher layer. For example, if you are using GPT partitions, you can set a PARTLABEL.

```
# parted /dev/loop0
(parted) name 1 foobar                                                    
(parted) print
Model: Loopback device (loopback)
Disk /dev/loop0: 105MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  104MB  103MB               foobar
```

This sets the partition label of partition 1 to "foobar".

You can identify it with `PARTLABEL=foobar` or find it in `/dev/disk/by-partlabel/`

```
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-partlabel/foobar 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 10 20:10 /dev/disk/by-partlabel/foobar -> ../../loop0p1
```

Similarly, if you use LUKS on top of LVM, you could go with VG/LV names.

---

As always with labels, take extra care to make sure each label doesn't exist more than once. There's a reason why UUIDs are meant to be "universally unique". You get a lot of problems when trying to use the wrong device; it can even cause data loss (e.g. if cryptswap formats the wrong device on boot).

Answer (score 2):

`cryptsetup` can create a label on a [cryptdevice](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/System_configuration#cryptdevice). Look in /dev/disk/by-label to make sure it matches. So

```
cryptdevice=LABEL={labelname}
```

[in the same way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming#by-label) as

```
root=LABEL=ROOT
```

works for a `ROOT` labelled root device